# How to sum the numbers from multi selected elements by class inside an div with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I'm trying to sum the values of the number of listeners in different servers which I've collected inside an div with *id="channel1"* and the num. of listeners is located into *span* element with class *stats*. I want to collect and sum all the values with class *'stats'* inside the div with id *'channel1'*.

Below is my HTML and jquery code:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="channel1">
                 <div id="kanali1-a">
                    <h4>Serveri 1*</h4>
                    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8000</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge"></span><br>
                    <span>Ky eshte serveri kryesor ku behet transmetimi</span> 
                 </div>

                 <div id="kanali1-b">
                    <h4>Serveri 2</h4>
                    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8004</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span><br>
                    <span></span> 
                 </div>

                 <div id="kanali1-c">
                    <h4>Serveri 3</h4>
                    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8006</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span><br>
                    <span></span> 
                 </div>

                  <div id="kanali1-d">
                    <h4>Serveri 4</h4>
                    <span> IP: radio-pendimi.com (all-inkl) Porta: 8000</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span><br>
                    <span></span> 
                 </div>

                 <div id="kanali1-e">
                    <h4>Serveri 5</h4>
                    <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8000</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span><br>
                    <span></span> 
                 </div>

                 <div id="kanali1-f">
                    <h4>Serveri 6</h4>
                    <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8004</span>
                    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span><br>
                    <span></span> 
                 </div> 
               </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
var statsCh1 = $('#channel1 .stats').text();
   var resCh1 = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<statsCh1.length; i++){
       resCh1 += statsCh1[i] << 0;
       //console.log(statsCh1[i]);
    }

   $('#kanal1Total').text(resCh1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
var sum = 0;
$('#channel1 .stats').each(function () {
    sum += (+ $(this).text());
});
$('#kanal1Total').text(sum);
```

Comment: This one does the job and is cleaner solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$('#channel1 .stats').text();` on multiple elements will just concat a list of strings together, so you'll end up with something like `"01010101010"`.

What you should do is iterate over each element. Here's an implementation with [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) & [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
// Iterate over each .stats element...
var values = $('#channel1 .stats').map(function() {
  // Make sure to parse the text as a Number...
  return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
}).get(); // Converts the elements to a native array
// Now sum the values that we've found above
var sum = values.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="channel1">
    <div id="kanali1-a">
        <h4>Serveri 1*</h4>
        <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8000</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge"></span>
        <br>
        <span>Ky eshte serveri kryesor ku behet transmetimi</span>
    </div>

    <div id="kanali1-b">
        <h4>Serveri 2</h4>
        <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8004</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
        <br>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div id="kanali1-c">
        <h4>Serveri 3</h4>
        <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8006</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
        <br>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div id="kanali1-d">
        <h4>Serveri 4</h4>
        <span> IP: radio-pendimi.com (all-inkl) Porta: 8000</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
        <br>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div id="kanali1-e">
        <h4>Serveri 5</h4>
        <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8000</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
        <br>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div id="kanali1-f">
        <h4>Serveri 6</h4>
        <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8004</span> Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
        <br>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is `var statsCh1 = $('#channel1 .stats').text();` only returns the text from the first element in the collection. It does not bring back the text of all the elements in the jQuery collection. So when you are looping, you are looping over a string.

So you need to loop over the collection and read the text from each individual element. One way is to use an each and just loop.

```
var total = 0;
$("#channel1 .stats").map(function(){
    total += parseInt( $(this).text() ) || 0;
});
console.log(total);
```

Another way is to use map and reduce. It is a bit of overkill since it is more looping, but it is something nice to have in the toolkit.

```js
var total = $("#channel1 .stats").map(function(){
   return parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;  //get the number from the spans, if not a number, set it to zero
}).get()  //turns jQuery object into actual array
.reduce(  //add up all of the indexes of the array to reduce it to one number
    function (p, c) { return p + c;}, 0  
);
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="channel1">
  <div id="kanali1-a">
    <h4>Serveri 1*</h4>
    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8000</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge"></span>
    <br>
    <span>Ky eshte serveri kryesor ku behet transmetimi</span> 
  </div>

  <div id="kanali1-b">
    <h4>Serveri 2</h4>
    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8004</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
    <br>
    <span></span> 
  </div>

  <div id="kanali1-c">
    <h4>Serveri 3</h4>
    <span> IP: 85.93.88.146 Porta: 8006</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
    <br>
    <span></span> 
  </div>

  <div id="kanali1-d">
    <h4>Serveri 4</h4>
    <span> IP: radio-pendimi.com (all-inkl) Porta: 8000</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
    <br>
    <span></span> 
  </div>

  <div id="kanali1-e">
    <h4>Serveri 5</h4>
    <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8000</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
    <br>
    <span></span> 
  </div>

  <div id="kanali1-f">
    <h4>Serveri 6</h4>
    <span> IP: 217.172.180.29 Porta: 8004</span>
    Duke degjuar: <span class="stats badge">10</span>
    <br>
    <span></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```